# Create a NavigationView stack and move from first view into last view in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationview

I have a NavigationView in SwiftUI and a couple of views, let's assume that we have [View a, View b, View c, View d].

What I want is to move from "View a" into the "View d" without showing "View b", "View c"
and being able to navigate back from "View d" to "c , b" reaching back to "a".

Comment: NavigationView does not allow this now. You need to implement something custom for such behavior.

Comment: @Asperi I think that I found a good temporarily workaround: this could happen by disabling navigation view animations by calling :         **UINavigationBar.setAnimationsEnabled(false)**
then in the final view you can reenable it by calling         **UINavigationBar.setAnimationsEnabled(true)**